# Create flags in SQL group by ID variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table similar to the one below, and I want to go through Var 1 - Var 3 to check for certain pattern, and create flags for each pattern accordingly.

[image]

Ideally to produce a table similar to the one below

[image]

What's the simplest and fastest way to do this in SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when v.var = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       max(case when v.var = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as b,
       max(case when v.var = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as c,
       max(case when v.var = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as d
from t cross apply
     (values (t.var1), (t.var2), (t.var3)) v(var)
group by t.id;
```

It simplifies the conditions by unpivoting the data first.  Of course, you can also use:

```
select id,
       max(case when 'A' in (var1, var2, var3) then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       max(case when 'B' in (var1, var2, var3) then 1 else 0 end) as b,
       max(case when 'C' in (var1, var2, var3) then 1 else 0 end) as c,
       max(case when 'D' in (var1, var2, var3) then 1 else 0 end) as d
from t
group by id;
```